# Custom folder (group) icons in Xcode's Project Navigation Pan

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

In the project navigator on the left, I want to give different folders (groups) different custom icons.

For instance, I have the files for my chat module in a folder called *Chat*. I want to change the icon for that folder to the chat icon that I have in the app. Is there any way I can accomplish this?

Comment: I believe this is not posible, because there are not folders (as is) they are groups and someones have a predefined icon as images assets.

Comment: I have modified the question. Thats a bummer. I have this huge project with hundreds of classes and dozens of modules. Its hard to navigate through it.

Comment: It sounds as a great idea, I hope someone know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is at all possible and I have not looked into it so this is just an idea, but if it is possible then you probably have to manually edit the project.pbxproj file within the xcodeproj file ([ctrl]+click/right click on the xcodeproj file and select *Show Package Contents*). It will probably take you a while to understand how pbxproj files work though.